# get data from database via php/json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can i get those variables and store the in my own variables? I want to get them in order to update some of them during the save process. I know that can happen via jquery/ajax or php.. but how I can do that correctly? I want for example to take the `[x]` and store it in my variable `A`.

```
      Array
    (
        [sliders] => Array
            (
                [c1] => Array
                    (
                        [content] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
//I WANT THAT VARIABLES: FROM title to additional style//
                                        [title] => 1
                                        [content_type] => image_content
                                        [content_url] => http://url.com
                                        [original_x] => -4px
                                        [original_y] => -27px
                                        [x] => -71.5
                                        [y] => -59
                                        [w] => 450
                                        [h] => 265
                                        [w_original] => 362
                                        [h_original] => 213
                                        [angle] => 0
                                        [opacity] => 100
                                        [order_position] => 10001
                                        [link_url] => 
                                        [matrix] => matrix(0.701111, 0, 0, 0.758491, 0, 0)
                                        [scaleX] => 0.70111111111111
                                        [scaleY] => 0.75849056603774
                                        [text_style] => 
                                        [additional_style] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [animation_fx] => Array
                                            (
                                                [fx_in] => 
                                                [fx_out] => 
                                            )

                                        [animation_times] => Array
                                            (
                                                [in_start] => 0
                                                [in_stop] => 1000
                                                [out_start] => 4000
                                                [out_stop] => 5000
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [duration] => 5
                        [overlap] => 0
                        [order_position] => 1
                        [min_z] => 10001
                        [max_z] => 10001
                    )

            )

        [width] => 450
        [height] => 300
        [back_color] => #ffffff
        [back_color_xyz] => Array
            (
                [x] => 8
                [y] => 50
                [z] => 0
            )

        [link_url] => 
        [title] => 
        [thumbnail] => 
        [id] => 0
    )
```

how can I get them via php? They are stored in the DB.

Comment: How did you print above data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - get data from db to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648511/php-get-data-from-db-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable variables to get the values, from `title` to `additional_style` array and store them in variables which are same as the array keys.

Here's the reference:

- [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
// suppose $arr is your original array

foreach($arr['sliders']['c1']['content'][0] as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;  // variable variables
    if($key == "additional_style"){
        break;
    }
}

echo "title: " . $title . "<br />";  // title
echo "content_type: " . $content_type . "<br />";  // content_type
echo "content_url: " . $content_url . "<br />";  // content_url
echo "original_x: " . $original_x . "<br />";  // original_x
echo "original_y: " . $original_y . "<br />";  // original_y
echo "x: " . $x . "<br />";  // x
echo "y: " . $y . "<br />";  // y
echo "w: " . $w . "<br />";  // w
echo "h: " . $h . "<br />";  // h
echo "w_original: " . $w_original . "<br />";  // w_original
echo "h_original: " . $h_original . "<br />";  // h_original
echo "angle: " . $angle . "<br />";  // angle
echo "opacity: " . $opacity . "<br />";  // opacity
echo "order_position: " . $order_position . "<br />";  // order_position
echo "link_url: " . $link_url . "<br />";  // link_url
echo "matrix: " . $matrix . "<br />";  // matrix
echo "scaleX: " . $scaleX . "<br />";  // scaleX
echo "scaleY: " . $scaleY . "<br />";  // scaleY
echo "text_style: " . $text_style . "<br />";  // text_style
echo "additional_style array: "; var_dump($additional_style);  // additional_style array
```

Output:

```
title: 1
content_type: image_content
content_url: http://url.com
original_x: -4px
original_y: -27px
x: -71.5
y: -59
w: 450
h: 265
w_original: 362
h_original: 213
angle: 0
opacity: 100
order_position: 10001
link_url:
matrix: matrix(0.701111, 0, 0, 0.758491, 0, 0)
scaleX: 0.70111111111111
scaleY: 0.75849056603774
text_style:
additional_style array:

array (size=0)
  empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Two additions to Rajdeep Paul's answer:

1. If your input is a JSON string, and not a PHP array, you could decode it giving a PHP object. Then you would refer the "content" objects like this:

   `$obj->sliders->c1->content[0]`

   instead of

   `$arr['sliders']['c1']['content'][0]`
2. Assigning an array to a variable variable:
   One can not directly assign values to a variable variable.
   But, if a variable is an array, you could assign its item values to a
   temporary array and then assign this temporary array to the variable variable.

Example that shows this - with a PHP object decoded from a JSON string:

```
$php_object = json_decode($json);
foreach($php_object->sliders->c1->content[0] as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $tmp_array = array();
        foreach($value as $akey => $avalue) {
            $tmp_array[] = $avalue;
        }
        $$key = $tmp_array;
    } else {
        $$key = $value;  // variable variables
    }
}
echo "x: " . $x . "<br />";  // x
echo "y: " . $y . "<br />";  // y
echo 'additional_style:<br />';  // additional_style
foreach($additional_style as $style) echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $style . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
x: -71.5
y: -59
additional_style:
   style_def_1
   style_def_2
   style_def_3
```